# jquery Autofill select with options from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm going to have a total of 4 dropdowns. What I'm thinking is creating 3 arrays (first is dropdown is hardcoded), and based what's picked on in the first array, the 2nd dropdown gets populated. How do I filter out what displays based on the first selection? I already know what all the options will be for the 2nd,3rd,4th menu. Here's what I'm thinking:

```
var secondDropdown = ['Cat|c1|1','Dog|d1|1','Banana|b1|2','Apple|a1|2','Car|c2|3','Boat|b2|3'] // here's where i'm lost. How do I create an array that has 3 values. first is the display text, second is the value and third is the filter.

<select id="menu1">
<option value="1">First Option</option>
<option value="2">Second Option</option>
<option value="3">Third Option</option>
</select>

<select id="menu2"></select>
```

Expected result of menu2 after selecting the first dropDown would be

```
<select id="menu2">
    <option value="c1">Cat</option>
    <option value="d1">Dog</option>
</select
```

So if I pick the first option, it'll take the value and match it up with the filter in the first array and populate the 2nd dropdown. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you plase show the expected HTML result of the `#menu2`?

Comment: there... changed it a bit to add a display text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be an approach:

```js
$(function() {


  var secondDropdown = [{
    filter: "1",
    values: [{
      value: "b1",
      text: "Boat"
    }, {
      value: "b2",
      text: "Boat2"
    }, {
      value: "b3",
      text: "Boat3"
    }]
  }, {
    filter: "2",
    values: [{
      value: "c1",
      text: "Cat"
    }, {
      value: "c2",
      text: "Cat2"
    }, {
      value: "c3",
      text: "Cat3"
    }]
  }];


  $('#menu1').change(function() {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    $('#menu2').html("");

    var content = secondDropdown.filter(function(elem) {
      return elem.filter == currentValue;
    });
    $.each(content[0] != undefined ? content[0].values : [], function(i, elem) {
      $('#menu2').append("<option value='" + elem.value + "'>" + elem.text + "</option>");
    });

  }).trigger("change");


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="menu1">
  <option value="1">First Option</option>
  <option value="2">Second Option</option>
  <option value="3">Third Option</option>
</select>

<select id="menu2"></select>
```

Comment: Is that a JSON object? when you're returning (elem.filter), is the '.filter' part referring to the filter in the object? Lastly, doing it like this, I guess i could just have 1 large object with menu2,menu3,menu4 options. How would I go about doing something like that? if elem.filter returns the values, i guess i would say elem.menu =='menu1', then somehow elem.filter at that point?

Comment: 1) thats an object, if you stringify it then it ll be a JSON. 2) The .filter is a jquery function, not referring to the object key 3) ofc yes u can create a more complex object that contain the filters for every select you need and then create the content filtering also with the select id

Comment: How does the elem.filter know to grab the first set of values if it's 1? What if the filter was a word instead of a number?

Comment: the filter function get every element of the array that match menu1 value with the filter property of the obj. Everything works number and words

Comment: still trying to wrap my brain around this... how would you filter if you wanted to do grand-children (child's child)? I appreciate all your help. Thanks!

Comment: i ll give you an example but i need to find some time

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Array, use more Arrays with options values.

```js
var secondDropdown = [
  ["Cat", "Dog", "Unicorn"],
  ["Banana", "Apple", "Strawberry", "Pear", "Rapsberry"],
  ["Car", "Boat"]
];

$("#menu1").on("change", function(){
  var drop2arr = secondDropdown[this.value-1];          
  $("#menu2").html(function(){
     return "<option>"+ (drop2arr.join("</option><option>")) +"</option>";
  });
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="menu1">
<option value="1">Animals</option>
<option value="2">Fruits</option>
<option value="3">Things</option>
</select>

<select id="menu2"></select>
```

Comment: 1 comment, 1 question... Comment: This only works because the values in the first dropdown are numbers, but in the 2nd dropdown, the values are words. There is gonna be 4 selects each populated by the previous one so this won't work. Question: on menu2, when you're returning, if i'm reading the code right, shouldn't there be an empty </option>? Also, how's the value being set?

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine.

```
var secondDropdown = ['cat|1','Dog|1','Banana|2','Apple|2','Car|3','Boat|3']; // here's where i'm lost. How do I create an array that has 2 values. first is the regular value and second value is the filter.
$("#menu1").on("change", function(){
    $("#menu2").html('');
    //Get current value of Menu1 on change event
    var value=$(this).val();
    for(var i = 0; i < secondDropdown.length; i++)
    {
        //Get associed values
        var splitted = secondDropdown[i].split('|');
        if(splitted[1] === value)
        {
            //append in the second select
            $("#menu2").append('<option value="'+splitted[1]+'">'+splitted[0]+'</option>');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: GIve me a sec while i go through this... thanks a lot!

Comment: I post this solution before you edit your post, so i work with your initial array.